# how to emulate linux command - "source filename -arg value" in python

Tags: python-3.x, execfile

I am trying to script the Linux instructions in python. I am not able to script the following in python.

source /usr/home/modelling.rc -m model

I tried subprocess.call(['/usr/home/modelling.rc', "-m", "model"])
***E: You can't execute me directly, you must source me!  source /usr/home/modelling.rc -m model

I also found that execfile() does the same job as source. But without giving the arguments, I am not able to run the file. Is there a way to source the file with arguments in python. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Like [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) or what?

Comment: I think you can't have it both ways (execute bash commands on a child, and modify a parent environment).

Comment: I am not sure if subprocess can do this.if you think it will, please help me..

Comment: @user3798648, what did you try? Post in your question.